# how to send DM message by USER ID and @Mention?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How to make the bot write a private message to the user, and through the specified **USER ID**, and **mention**

**Example:**

```
!private 660033203473743873 Hello
!private @User Hello
```

**My code**

```
client.on('message', message => {

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

  if (command === 'private') {

      member.send({
      content: `${args[1]}`,
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using `args` incorrectly.
`args` is an array of the whole message therefore `args[0]` will return `!private` in your case.
Working example:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; //If message is sent by a bot or does not start with the prefix
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); //Getting the message arguments
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); //Receiving the command

    if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Please provide a user to message."); //If user was not provided
    const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]); //Get the member
    if (!member) return message.channel.send("I could not find the user you provided"); //If the member was not found
    if (!member.id || !member.tag) member = member.user; //Making sure the user is correct

    try {
        member = await message.guild.members.fetch(user); //Getting the guild member
    } catch() {
        member = null;
    }
    if (!member) return message.channel.send("The user you mentioned is not in this server."); //Double checking the user is in the server

    if (command.toLowerCase() == "private") { //Command is equal to private
        member.send(args.slice(1).join(" ")); //Send the member a message
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am sending! private 660033203473743873 test.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or any output?

Comment: member = await message.guild.members.fetch(user); //Getting the guild member
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
 
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: member = await message.guild.members.fetch(user); //Getting the guild member
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: You have not entered the code correctly, please take note of line 1.

Comment: } catch() {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: I have given you a piece of working code, please work your errors out on your own.